Calculus for the practical man Chapter 4 problem 18
The hypotenuse AB of a right triangle ABC remains 5 inches long while the other two sides change, the side AC increasing at the rate of 2 in. per min. At what rate is the area of the triangle changing when AC is just 3 inches?
The answer given by the book is $\frac{7}{4}$ sq. in. min so I'd appreciate the worked solution and revision of why my method didn't work.
My calculations
Beginning with given material,
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=2in/s$$
$$A=\frac{1}{2}xy$$
In terms of y, $A=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{25-y^2}*y=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{25y^2-y^4}$ Then differentiating, $dA=\frac{6y}{\sqrt{25y^2-y^4}}*\frac{dy}{dt}$ finally becoming, $\frac{dA}{dt}=\frac{12y}{\sqrt{25y^2-y^4}}$ which when AC equals three yields three inches per minute from the derived function when the answer in the book is $\frac{7}{4}$ sq. in. min.

Your overall reasoning is right, but you computed the derivative of $A$ incorrectly. $\frac{dA}{dt}$ should be
$\frac{dA}{dt} =  \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2}\cdot(25y^2-y^4)^{-1/2}\cdot (50y-4y^3)\cdot \frac{dy}{dt}\right)$
Plugging in $y=3$ and $\frac{dy}{dt} = 2$ will give you $\frac{7}{4}$.

Thank you, just getting used to calculus that's all.
